# Convert series of WKT to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, convert, sql-server, well-known-text

I have seen am ability in `SQL Server 2008 Spatial Tools` [here](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools) that saves result of query as shapefile..I am intrested in how to do this task using C#..Is there any way to do this?I found ways to convert WKT to WKB and so on but I could not figur out how to convert them to .shp.I found a tool called `ogr2ogr` but I dont know how to use it in my C# code

Comment: are you creating a view from this query?

Comment: @mapBaker No,I just load this query to a DataTable and Can get geometry from it.it is like this Polygon((1 2,2 3,3 4,1 2)) and I want to convert this to a shape file